# Error with NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am using `NIntegrate` and getting an error message

```
d = 25/100; U1 = 52/100; U2 = 30/100;
Ux[px_, py_, pz_] = 2 U1/3 (Cos[px] + Cos[py] + Cos[pz]);
Uy[px_, py_, pz_] = 2 U2/3 (Cos[px] + Cos[py] - Cos[pz]);
U0[px_, py_, pz_] = (Ux[px, py, pz] + Uy[px, py, pz])/2;
U3[px_, py_, pz_] = (Ux[px, py, pz] - Uy[px, py, pz])/2;
P0[T_, v_, x_, px_, py_, pz_] = 
  1 - 2 (U0[px, py, pz] (2 d^2 + x) - U3[px, py, pz] x)/Sqrt[
      d^2 + x]/(4 d^2 + 4 x + v^2) Tanh[Sqrt[d^2 + x]/T];
PdP0[T_, v_, x_, px_, py_, pz_] = 
  P0[T, v, x, px, py, pz] D[P0[T, v, x, px, py, pz], x];
P1[T_, v_, x_, px_, py_, 
   pz_] = -2 U3[px, py, 
    pz] v d/Sqrt[d^2 + x]/(4 d^2 + 4 x + v^2) Tanh[Sqrt[d^2 + x]/T];
PdP1[T_, v_, x_, px_, py_, pz_] = 
  P1[T, v, x, px, py, pz] D[P1[T, v, x, px, py, pz], x];
P2[T_, v_, x_, px_, py_, 
   pz_] = -2 U0[px, py, 
    pz] I v d/Sqrt[d^2 + x]/(4 d^2 + 4 x + v^2) Tanh[
    Sqrt[d^2 + x]/T];
PdP2[T_, v_, x_, px_, py_, pz_] = 
  P2[T, v, x, px, py, pz] D[P2[T, v, x, px, py, pz], x];
P3[T_, v_, x_, px_, py_, 
   pz_] = -2 (U3[px, py, pz] (2 d^2 + x) - U0[px, py, pz] x)/Sqrt[
     d^2 + x]/(4 d^2 + 4 x + v^2) Tanh[Sqrt[d^2 + x]/T];
PdP3[T_, v_, x_, px_, py_, pz_] = 
  P3[T, v, x, px, py, pz] D[P3[T, v, x, px, py, pz], x];
F[T_, v_, x_, px_, py_, 
   pz_] =
  (PdP0[T, v, x, px, py, pz] - PdP1[T, v, x, px, py, pz] - 
      PdP2[T, v, x, px, py, pz] - 
      PdP3[T, v, x, px, py, pz])/(P0[T, v, x, px, py, pz]^2 - 
      P1[T, v, x, px, py, pz]^2 - P2[T, v, x, px, py, pz]^2 - 
      P3[T, v, x, px, py, pz]^2);
F1[T_, v_, x_] := 
  8*NIntegrate[
    F[T, v, x, px, py, pz], {px, 0, \[Pi]}, {py, 0, \[Pi]}, {pz, 
     0, \[Pi]}];
```

[image]

The integrand has singularity if 2U1/3(cospx+cospy+cospz)=d coth(d/T)  or 2U2/3(cospx+cospy-cospz)=d coth(d/T).

For the `d U1 U2` that were used here, if `T<1/4/ArcCoth[104/25]`,  first singularity(yellow) exist.  If `T<1/4/ArcCoth[12/5]`, second singularity (blue) also exist. 
So I write the integral into five portions when `T<1/4/ArcCoth[12/5]` by the method provided by @Akku14 [NIntegral takes long time](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173048/nintegral-takes-long-time/173071#173071), similar problem just changed the integrand a bit.

[image]

`int1` projection of blue part, `int2` right above blue but in yellow, `int3` the rest part of yellow, `int4` right above yellow, `int5` rest part.

```
int1[T_?NumericQ] := 
  8*NIntegrate[
    NIntegrate[
     F[T, 0, 0, px, py, pz], {pz, 0, 
      ArcCos[75/104 Coth[1/4/T] - Cos[px] - Cos[py]], 
      ArcCos[Cos[px] + Cos[py] - 5/4 Coth[1/4/T]], Pi}, 
     Method -> "PrincipalValue"], {px, 0, 
     ArcCos[5/4 Coth[1/4/T] - 2]}, {py, 0, 
     ArcCos[5/4 Coth[1/4/T] - Cos[px] - 1]}];
int2[T_?NumericQ] := 
  8*NIntegrate[
    NIntegrate[
     F[T, 0, 0, px, py, pz], {pz, 0, 
      ArcCos[-Cos[px] - Cos[py] + 75/104 Coth[1/4/T]], Pi}, 
     Method -> "PrincipalValue"], {px, 0, 
     ArcCos[5/4 Coth[1/4/T] - 2]}, {py, 
     ArcCos[5/4 Coth[1/4/T] - Cos[px] - 1], 
     ArcCos[75/104 Coth[1/4/T] - 1 - Cos[px]]}];
int3[T_?NumericQ] := 
  8*NIntegrate[
    NIntegrate[
     F[T, 0, 0, px, py, pz], {pz, 0, 
      ArcCos[75/104 Coth[1/4/T] - Cos[px] - Cos[py]], Pi}, 
     Method -> "PrincipalValue"], {px, ArcCos[5/4 Coth[1/4/T] - 2], 
     ArcCos[75/104 Coth[1/4/T] - 2]}, {py, 0, 
     ArcCos[75/104 Coth[1/4/T] - 1 - Cos[px]]}];
int4[T_?NumericQ] := 
  8*NIntegrate[
    F[T, 0, 0, px, py, pz], {pz, 0, Pi}, {px, 0, 
     ArcCos[75/104 Coth[1/4/T] - 2]}, {py, 
     ArcCos[75/104 Coth[1/4/T] - 1 - Cos[px]], Pi}];
int5[T_?NumericQ] := 
 8*NIntegrate[
   F[T, 0, 0, px, py, pz], {pz, 0, Pi}, {px, 
    ArcCos[75 /104 Coth[1/4/T] - 2], Pi}, {py, 0, Pi}]; 
F0[T_] = int1[T] + int2[T] + int3[T] + int4[T] + int5[T];
```

When I am running `F0[0.55]`, I get this error message
"NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries". It came from `int2` and `int3` only after evaluate them separately.

The error message does not appear for values like `F0[0.5]`

What does this message mean and why it appears?

Comment: You have a lot of code to wade through. Have you done some troubleshooting on your own? For instance, your `F0` expression is simply a sum of five contributions. Have you at least run them separately with that problematic input to see which ones are responsible for the error?

Comment: There are several similar problems on this site.  If you search for `inumri` you'll find the ones whose OPs were thoughtful enough to include the message name.